# How to make a query in Slick 3 to select from DB with count from children tables

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

How I can make this query in slick 3.0 ?

```
Select *,(SELECT COUNT(*) from flashcards WHERE setId = flashcards_sets.id ) as allCount,(SELECT COUNT(*) from flashcards WHERE studied = true AND setId = flashcards_sets.id ) as studiedCount FROM flashcards_sets;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private def filterByFlashCardQuery(id: Int): Query[FlashCards, FlashCard, Seq] =
    flashcards.filter(_.setId === id && _.studied = true)

def findByFlashcardLength(flashcardId: Int):Future[Int] = {
    try db.run(filterByFlashCardQuery(flashcardId).length.result)
    finally println("db.close")//db.close
  }
```

```

Comment: Could use some elaboration as to how it solves the problem.